# How to get div to fit contents without vertical scroll bars?

Tags: html, css

As you can see I have a div that fits 3 images. When you hover over the images, the images grow. But the surrounding div does not and scroll bars appear. I do not want this.

You could hide the y axis overflow, however if I do that I won't get the zoom effect on the bottom of the images, which is something I want. So that is not ab option.

How can I fix this without any compromise?

```css
h1 {
    letter-spacing: -.015em;
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

.subtitle{
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    h1 {
        letter-spacing: -.015em;
        font-size: 4.5rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.1;
    }
    .subtitle{
        font-size: 1.65em;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .img-container {
        width:345px !important;
        height:580px !important;
    }
}


.img-container {
    width:173px;
    height:290px;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.img-container:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05); 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="home" class="lg:pl-28 flex flex-wrap flex-row w-full">
            <div class="flex flex-col w-full lg:w-6/12 xl:w-5/12 justify-center pl-12 lg:pl-0 pr-28 pt-36 lg:pt-32 xl:pt-52">
                <p class="text-md lg:text-lg text-left text-gray-500">Post Title</p>
                <h1 class="mb-4 pt-5 pb-9 text-left">Title 1</h1>
                <p class="subtitle leading-normal text-gray-500 mb-8 text-left">Subtitle</p>
            </div>
            
            <!--Right Col-->
            <div class="w-full lg:w-6/12 xl:w-7/12 overflow-x-hidden flex items-center lg:pt-32 xl:pt-52">
                <div class="flex gap-4">
                    <div class="flex-initial img-container">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/345x580">
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-initial img-container">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/345x580">
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-initial img-container">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/345x580">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do is add

```
margin-top: 15px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
```

to `.img-container`

That makes the most sense, to me.

Answer (score 1):

You could add padding to the parent div so that the scrollbar won't appear because it has space in the bottom, it won't affect the child's growth.

set `.w-full {padding-bottom: 15px;}`

Full code here

```css
h1 {
    letter-spacing: -.015em;
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

.subtitle{
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
.w-full {padding-bottom: 15px;}
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    h1 {
        letter-spacing: -.015em;
        font-size: 4.5rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.1;
    }
    .subtitle{
        font-size: 1.65em;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .img-container {
        width:345px !important;
        height:580px !important;
    }
}


.img-container {
    width:173px;
    height:290px;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.img-container:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05); 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="home" class="lg:pl-28 flex flex-wrap flex-row w-full">
            <div class="flex flex-col w-full lg:w-6/12 xl:w-5/12 justify-center pl-12 lg:pl-0 pr-28 pt-36 lg:pt-32 xl:pt-52">
                <p class="text-md lg:text-lg text-left text-gray-500">Post Title</p>
                <h1 class="mb-4 pt-5 pb-9 text-left">Title 1</h1>
                <p class="subtitle leading-normal text-gray-500 mb-8 text-left">Subtitle</p>
            </div>
            
            <!--Right Col-->
            <div class="w-full lg:w-6/12 xl:w-7/12 overflow-x-hidden flex items-center lg:pt-32 xl:pt-52">
                <div class="flex gap-4">
                    <div class="flex-initial img-container">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/345x580">
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-initial img-container">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/345x580">
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-initial img-container">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/345x580">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
h1 {
    letter-spacing: -.015em;
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

.subtitle{
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    h1 {
        letter-spacing: -.015em;
        font-size: 4.5rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.1;
    }
    .subtitle{
        font-size: 1.65em;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .img-container {
        width:345px !important;
    }
}


.img-container {
    width:173px;
    height:290px;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.img-container:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05); 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="home" class="lg:pl-28 flex flex-wrap flex-row w-full">
            <div class="flex flex-col w-full lg:w-6/12 xl:w-5/12 justify-center pl-12 lg:pl-0 pr-28 pt-36 lg:pt-32 xl:pt-52">
                <p class="text-md lg:text-lg text-left text-gray-500">Post Title</p>
                <h1 class="mb-4 pt-5 pb-9 text-left">Title 1</h1>
                <p class="subtitle leading-normal text-gray-500 mb-8 text-left">Subtitle</p>
            </div>
            
            <!--Right Col-->
            <div class="w-full lg:w-6/12 xl:w-7/12 flex items-center lg:pt-32 xl:pt-52">
                <div class="flex gap-4">
                    <div class="flex-initial img-container">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/345x580">
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-initial img-container">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/345x580">
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-initial img-container">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/345x580">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>
```

Comment: Did you just remove the height?

Comment: no , i removed the `overflow-x-hidden` from the outer div of the `Right Col`

Comment: Unfortunately I need that :/

Comment: dont forget to upvote